# How to extract values from List<T> into M x 1 double[,] array concisely with less line of code?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, transformation, performance

Is it possible to extract values from a `List<T>` into a *M x 1* double[,] array concisely will less lines of codes?

I have a type defined as:

```
public class Trajectory
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    // ... more codes
}
```

And Vector3 is defined as :

```
    public struct Vector3
    {
        public float X;
        public float Y;
        public float Z;

        public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Z = z;
        }
        // ... more vector3 operators
     }
```

At the moment I have `List<Trajectory> trajectory`. It has 80 entries max. I'd like to store only the X, Y, X values of each entry in `trajectory` as *240 x 1* `double[,]` array (in the order of X, then Y, then Z values).

My current solution is rather long-winding and ugly. Here it goes:

```
            // take a snapshot of current trajectory
            List<Entry> tempEntry = new List<Entry> (Entries);

            // create a temporary vector3Values
            List<Vector3> vector3Values = new List<Vector3>();

            foreach (Entry e in tempEntry)
            {
                vector3Values.Add(new Vector3(e.Position.X, e.Position.Y, e.Position.Z));
            } 

            /* Start an index at 0.
             * This is for foreach iteration to extract the value of x, y, and z from each vector3
             */
            int index = 0;

            // find the size of the list, in case max limit is changed
            int listCount = inputVector3.Count;

            /* set the length of the new array by multiplying the size of the list by 3.
             * We want:
             * [x1 x2 x3...xn y1 y2 y3...yn z1 z2 z3...zn]'.
             * Therefore, the size of the reshaped array is three times of the original array             *
             */
            int maxRowLength = listCount * 3;

            // create double[,] variable to store the reshaped data, three times the length of the actual list. 
            double[,] result = new double[maxRowLength, 1];

            // start going for each vector, then store the x components in the double[,] array.
            foreach (Vector3 vector3 in inputVector3)
            {
                result[index, 0] = vector3.X;
                index++;
            }

            /* continuing from the previous index value, start going for each vector, 
             * then store the z components in the double[,] array.
             */
            foreach (Vector3 vector3 in inputVector3)
            {
                result[index, 0] = vector3.Y;
                index++;
            }

            /* continuing from the previous index value, start going for each vector, 
             * then store the z components in the double[,] array.
             */
            foreach (Vector3 vector3 in inputVector3)
            {
                result[index, 0] = vector3.Z;
                index++;
            }
```

At the end of the day I got what I wanted. *M x 1* double[,] array. I use double[,] for interoperability with Matlab's MWArray object that I need at this moment.

So, the question is, is there a concise way to accomplish what I am doing here?

**EDITED:** This transformation will be needed a number of times per seconds (Thanks to Chris Sinclair for bringing up this issue), however, this is not an issue at the moment.

Comment: it's a `Double[,]` but the it's always `Double[n,1]` with the 2nd dimension being 0? (where `n` is the total number of `X`, `Y` and `Z` entries)

Comment: Now when you say "quickly/efficiently", do you want the best performance wise at runtme, or the simplest to maintain/read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like the following to avoid looping three times:

```
var result = new double[entries.Count * 3, 1];

for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
{
    result[i, 0] = entries[i].Position.X;
    result[i + entries.Count, 0] = entries[i].Position.Y;
    result[i + entries.Count * 2, 0] = entries[i].Position.Z;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "quick/efficient" method of doing this, avoiding the general enumeration of Linq might be considered. Though since you state you only have 80 entries max, I doubt it's an issue unless you're doing this *many, many, many* times per second.

At any rate, here's a single iteration using a standard for loop while also minimizing element lookup and struct copying (I hope):

```
int length = inputVector3.Count;

double[,] result = new double[length * 3, 1];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    var vector = inputVector3[i];
    result[i, 0] = vector.X;
    result[i + length, 0] = vector.Y;
    result[i + length * 2, 0] = vector.Z;
}

return result;
```

I'm not *positive* if this is faster than the other options (mostly thinking about the math of `i + length` and `i + length * 2` portions); best to just try them out.

Comment: Hm... We will be doing this _many, many, many_ times per second.

Comment: @IwanKelaiah Then I'd suggest you setup some way of benchmarking performance before/after implementing any of the ideas here. It's important to accurately _identify_ the current bottlenecks of the code and verify that this is one.

Comment: Actually, performance-wise is not crucial at this stage. I'm more concerned about my ugly and long winding code. I'll modify the question's title description for clarity.

Comment: @IwanKelaiah Then it doesn't matter. Put all this logic in its own self-contained method, make it easy to read/maintain (and one that you understand how it operates), then benchmark it later when you go to discover bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like my answer at all, but you could write a linq statement like this. I can't promise it will be faster, but it's a different approach to try:

```
 List<Vector3> vectors = new List<Vector3>();
 //Select() will isolate the float value [X/Y/Z] of each type from the collection
 //Concat() will merge the selected float[]'s to make 
 //  one large array containing [x1,x2,x3...y1,y2,y3...z1,z2,z3...]
 float[] values = vectors.Select(e => e.X)
                         .Concat(vectors.Select(e => e.Y)
                         .Concat(vectors.Select(e => e.Z))).ToArray();
 for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
 {
      result[i, 0] = values[i];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the LINQ command SelectMany is exactly what you're looking for.

Given List trajectory, here's what I would do:

```
double[] result = trajectory.SelectMany(t => new double[] { t.Position.X, t.Position.Y, t.Position.Z }).ToArray();
```

What this says is: from the list of Trajectories, make an array out of the X Y and Z, and then join them all together into a big array. I've verified that this preserves order, but I don't know if this improves performance.

Comment: I believe the resulting array should contain [x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2] rather than [x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2].

Comment: Yeah, my answer was going to be this until I realized he needed [x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2], which is why I did it the way I did in my answer.

Comment: @Lily I'd be happy to reduce my multi-line solution to one. However, as Brandon Gano pointed out, my result should be [x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2].

Comment: Ah, my mistake. If you are looking for [x1, x2, x3..., y1, y2, y3...] then I wholeheartedly support Corylulu's solution. Mine gives [x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2...]